# How to use "_blank" or "_new" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In HTML, if I wanted a link to open in a new window, I'd adopt **target="_blank"** like this:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/img.png" /></a>
```

How do I add the **"_blank"** to rails? Here's the code I so far for the link (but it currently opens in the same tab/window):

```
<%= link_to image_tag("img.png"), 'http://www.website.com/' %>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think it's like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag('img.png'), 'http://www.website.com', target: '_blank' %>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: That worked... Thanks! **target: "_blank"** also worked. I'm assuming this other version only works on recent versions of rails (I'm using 3.2.2).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering how to achieve this when passing a block:

`<%= link_to(product.link, target: '_blank') do %>`

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the default action of the link in js as

```
$('#button-id').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();      
});
```

The preventDefault() function prevents the default action of the event

Answer (score 0):

you can also do `target: :_blank` if you prefer to use a symbol