# Difference between :target => '_blank' and target: = "_blank"

Tags: ruby

I recently asked a question ([heres the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290335/how-to-use-blank-or-new-in-rails)) regarding opening a link in a new page. I found there were two answers.

```
:target => '_blank' 
target: "_blank"
```

I was hoping someone could explain the difference between single and double quotations and why both of the above work. I understand the second option is only achievable on more recent versions of rails (I'm using 3.2.2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between colon ":" and fat arrow "=>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198811/whats-the-difference-between-colon-and-fat-arrow)

Comment: You're probably right @muistooshort. Thanks for pointing out the other post.

Comment: No worries, this seems to come up a fair bit and the duplicates are difficult to find, searching for "=>" or ":" really isn't very productive :)

Comment: @glennm symbolhound enables you to search for syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically, this is Ruby's hash,   ( for more info, please refer to  "@mu is too shot"'s resource )

```
# always works (works both in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9)
:target => '_blank'    

# works in 1.9 only 
target: "_blank"
```

both of them can assign hash's elements.

however the code below is incorrect.

```
# this is incorrect
target: = "_blank"
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "classic" and "1.9" style, there's the style that always works and the new alternative style that only works in limited cases: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004344/479863

Comment: But `=>` still isn't a 1.8 thing, it is perfectly valid and often necessary in 1.9. Yes, I'm on a crusade against the shiny new (and broken) alternative Hash literal syntax :)

Comment: @SiweiShen, thanks for picking up my error in the second example. I've fixed the error so it doesn't become the focus.

Comment: @muistooshort, I just read your comments on the link you provided. I'm interested to learn more so I'll read up on it. But I liked your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
1.9.2-p290 :009 > { :name => "soundar" } == { name: "soundar" }
=> true
```