# Inserting a weblink using link_to on rails

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

I'm using bootstrap on rails and struggling to figure out how to attach a link to a button so that it opens a web address in a new tab.

The code is:

```
<%= link_to "Learn more about the Royal Lancers»", "#", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```

I'm trying to link the button in a new tab to

"https://www.army.mod.uk/who-we-are/corps-regiments-and-units/royal-armoured-corps/royal-lancers/"

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [How to use "_blank" or "_new" in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290335/how-to-use-blank-or-new-in-rails); adding `target: '_blank'` opens the link in a new tab.

```
<%= link_to "Learn more about the Royal Lancers»", "#", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", target: '_blank'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<%= link_to "The Royal Lancers »", "https://www.army.mod.uk/who-we-are/corps-regiments-and-units/royal-armoured-corps/royal-lancers/", target: '_blank', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```